# Two arrays, int and string, how do I display strings with corresponding ints?

Tags: c++, arrays

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string iceCream[5] = {"vanilla", "butter pecan", "superman", "chocolate fudge", "strawberry"};
    int iceCreamscoops[5];
    int totalScoops = 0;

    cout << "enter the total amount of scoops for each icecream flavor\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cin >> iceCreamscoops[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << iceCream[i] << " = " << iceCreamscoops[i] << " have been sold"
             << "\n";
        totalScoops = totalScoops + iceCreamscoops[i];
    }
    cout << totalScoops << " total icecream scoops sold";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        // Change < to > if you want to find the smallest element
        if (iceCreamscoops[0] < iceCreamscoops[i])
            iceCreamscoops[0] = iceCreamscoops[i];
    }
    cout << "\nMost popular flavor/flavors and scoops sold = " << iceCreamscoops[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if (iceCreamscoops[0] > iceCreamscoops[i])
            iceCreamscoops[0] = iceCreamscoops[i];
    }

    cout << "\nLeast popular flavor/flavors and scoops sold = " << iceCreamscoops[0];
}
```

In the code above I need to display the ice cream that sold the most and least alongside its flavor. How do I display the string alongside the inputted value? I tried to compare the code by taking the found value and comparing it to the string array.

Comment: It looks like you are close - but make your code compileable (a [mcve]) and you'll get help quickly.

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: `if(iceCreamscoops[0] < iceCreamscoops[i])` -- You are comparing every ice cream value with the first one.  This is obviously wrong in determining the minimum or maximum.  What if there were 25 ice cream flavors?  Would you compare each one with only the first, or would you have some variable telling you which ice cream flavor *so far* is the minimum or maximum?

Comment: I suppose it is a bit ramshackle but for this case I only have to compare 5 values. Do enlighten me though about what the issues with this are? should I set up separate variables for least and greatest?

Comment: Yes, separate variables for least and greatest.  Then possibly it will make sense on how to write the loop.

Comment: Ok so I tried it but my least keeps throwing up massively huge numbers.
enter the total amount of scoops for each icecream flavor
1

2

3

4

5

vanilla = 1 have been sold
butter pecan = 2 have been sold
superman = 3 have been sold
chocolate fudge = 4 have been sold
strawberry = 5 have been sold
15 total icecream scoops sold
Most popular flavor/flavors and scoops sold = 5
Least popular flavor/flavors and scoops sold = 426844668

I changed iceCreamscoops[0] to scoopLeast and scoopGreatest inside the if loop

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<5;++i)`
`{`
      '// Change < to > if you want to find the smallest element'
       'if(iceCreamscoops[0] < iceCreamscoops[i])'
           scoopGreatest = iceCreamscoops[i];
          
 `}`
   `cout << "\nMost popular flavor/flavors and scoops sold = "<<scoopGreatest;`
   `for(int i=0;i<5;++i)`
 `{`
          `if(iceCreamscoops[0] > iceCreamscoops[i])`
        `scoopLeast = iceCreamscoops[i];'
            
        
 `}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You don't need to include `cmath` for what you're doing.)

It might be helpful to keep track of the greatest and least number of scoops as well as the index of each, instead of overwrite `iceCreamScoops[0]`. For example, we could create variables `mostScoops` + `indexOfMostScoops` and `leastScoops` + `indexOfLeastScoops`, as in the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string iceCream[5] = {"vanilla", "butter pecan", "superman", "chocolate fudge", "strawberry "};
    int iceCreamScoops[5];
    int totalScoops = 0;
    int mostScoops = -1, leastScoops = 1E6;
    int indexOfMostScoops = -1, indexOfLeastScoops = -1;

    cout << "Enter the total amount of scoops for each icecream flavor.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << iceCream[i] << ": ";
        cin >> iceCreamScoops[i];

        totalScoops += iceCreamScoops[i];

        if (iceCreamScoops[i] > mostScoops)
        {
            mostScoops = iceCreamScoops[i];
            indexOfMostScoops = i;
        }

        if (iceCreamScoops[i] < leastScoops)
        {
            leastScoops = iceCreamScoops[i];
            indexOfLeastScoops = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nThe total number of scoops is " << totalScoops << ".\n";
    cout << "The most popular flavor is " << iceCream[indexOfMostScoops] << " with " << mostScoops << " scoops.\n";
    cout << "The least popular flavor is " << iceCream[indexOfLeastScoops] << " with " << leastScoops << " scoops.\n";
}
```

(Of course, you might want to add checks to make sure the user only inputs non negative integers as number of scoops.)

Edit:

If you want to identify all flavors with a specific number of scoops (e.g. the largest number of scoops), you don't even need to keep track of the indices. For example, you could just do something like:

```cpp
cout << "\nThe greatest number of scoops is " << mostScoops << ".\n"
     << "The following flavors had this number of scoops:\n";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (iceCreamScoops[i] == mostScoops)
    {
        cout << "  " << iceCream[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The basic idea to find a maximum value is to start off with a value that is smaller than any value expected (such as `-1` scoops), and then update this maximum value each time we come across a value greater than the current maximum value.

Similarly, to find a minimum value, we can start off with a value that is greater than any expected value (such as `1E6` scoops), and then update this minimum value whenever we come across a smaller value.

Comment: One thing, what if the user inputs the same number more then once? How would I go about it?Like displaying more than one icecream for least or most popular?

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the if statements as well?

Comment: Last question, when inputting values how can I ignore letters and symbols?

Comment: For that, you would need to read in a string and then separately perform checks and extract integer values, but that’s a completely different question... Maybe work through a full C++ tutorial and then post a new question if you’re still stuck.